# sql запрос с использованием if else

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Как правильно оформить следующий запрос с использованием sql конструкции if else?
должно получится следующие условие

```
IF ((SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = $a)!= NULL) 
THEN (SELECT adress FROM users WHERE name = $a) 
ELSE (SELECT adress FROM users WHERE lastname = $b)
```

Нужно проверить есть ли значение поле таблицы, если есть то выполнить запрос по этому полю, иначе по другому полю, не могу найти верный синтаксис

Comment: Движок базы MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас *MySQL*, то в нем есть функция `COALESCE`, которая возвращает первое значение не равное `NULL`. Поэтому `IF` тут не потребуется.

```
SELECT `adress` FROM `users` WHERE COALESCE(`name`, `lastname`) = $a;
```

**Дополнено**

С учетом открывшихся обстоятельств поступаем так:

```
SELECT adress FROM users WHERE name IS NULL AND lastname = $b OR name = $a;
```

В *PostgreSQL* тоже есть функция `COALESCE`, но поскольку по новым вашим условиям сравнение разных полей должно происходит с разными значениями, этот вариант не подойдет.

Comment: У меня для name и lastname разные значения подставляются, я использую postgresql

Comment: В первой версии вопроса это было не так :) Сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Верно) Логика в том, что если имя не заполнено то мы ищем по фамилии

Comment: @ИгорьВолков, в PostgreSQL нет IF-ов (они есть plpgsql - синтаксисе хранимых процедур). Хотя, ваш код больше похож именно на кусок хранимки (ибо сравниваются результаты подзапросов), но на него никак не катит из-за корявости. В PostgreSQL используется CASE

Comment: @Vitalts Можете помочь с этим запросом с использованием case?

Comment: @ИгорьВолков а зачем вам `CASE` в данном запросе?

Comment: @ИгорьВолков я только что увидел, что таблицы-то разные. Это не опечатка? Таблицы `users` и `useres`?

Answer (score 1):

```
with fl as
(
    select address, 0 as idx
    from users
    where name = $a
    union all
    select address, 1 as idx
    from users
    where lastname = $b
)
select address
from fl
order by idx asc
limit 1
```